# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS and app crash

Tags: iphone, exception

I have a table view and and tapping on any cell there is a detail view, my app get crashed when returning from detail to table list view, after going in detail view more than once.

```
    #0  0x32d98f1c in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x358da150 in _UIView ()
#2  0x358da040 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] ()
#3  0x358da080 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] ()
#4  0x358da080 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] ()
#5  0x358d9f38 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:] ()
#6  0x358f81dc in -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] ()
#7  0x359af870 in -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] ()
#8  0x35900180 in -[UIView dealloc] ()
#9  0x374ffd7a in -[NSObject(NSObject) release] ()
#10 0x358f8230 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] ()
#11 0x35900180 in -[UIView dealloc] ()
#12 0x359afffc in -[UIScrollView dealloc] ()
#13 0x374ffd7a in -[NSObject(NSObject) release] ()
#14 0x3516f7f4 in __delayedPerformCleanup ()
#15 0x3754d526 in CFRunLoopTimerInvalidate ()
#16 0x375522ac in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#17 0x37521a90 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#18 0x3752150a in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#19 0x37521418 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#20 0x33e76d24 in GSEventRunModal ()
#21 0x3591d57c in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#22 0x3591a558 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

How can i track the main reason behind this crash.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ah yes, try looking at line 437 of your code.

Comment: there is a commented line at line 437..

Comment: And how would we know that? You're over-releasing a view but there's no way anyone can say much more than that without seeing any code.

Answer (score 2):

> I think in detailView dealloc method you are releasing an object which
>   is already release. it may be one of the reason to crash the app

Answer (score 0):

Could it possible, that you reuse the DetailViewController Variable and only change the Data ?

Because i think that's a retain/release problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rerun with zombies enabled. That should help you to pin point the problem which is most likely to be a pointer to a released object.

Comment: its not happening every time i return from detailview, but it happens on its own. Some time crash occurs after viewing 3,4 cell's detail and sometime its not even crashing after viewing the detail more than 10-15 time.

Comment: Same comment 3 times!  It is not happening on its own, it is happening because of code errors.  Do turn on Zombies and the other memory debugging options.

Comment: This is why Zombies can help. Read up on them and turn them on. They will show you if you are trying to send a message to a dealloc'd object pointer.